# Adding an eventListener to a div that can refer to the object that created the div

Tags: javascript, this, addeventlistener

I have an object that counts chars in an input and displays the number of chars in a div next to the input. I want to add a click event listener to the div that when clicked invokes a function in the object that created the div. I'm confusing myself now so here is some code:

```
var CharDisplay = function(input, max) {
    this.input = input;
    this.maxChars = max;
    this.direction = "countUp";

    this.div = document.createElement("div");
    this.div.setAttribute("class", "charCounter");
    this.input.parentNode.appendChild(this.div);

    var that = this; // I don't like doing this

    // This function toggles the direction property and tells the extension
    // to update localStorage with the new state of this char counter
    var toggleDirection = function() {
            that.direction = that.direction === "countUp" ? "countDown" : "countUp";    
            that.update();
            chrome.extension.sendRequest({
                    "method" : "updateCharCounter",
                    "id" : that.input.id,
                    "state" : { 
                            "direction" : that.direction,
                            "limit" : that.maxChars
                    }
            });
    }

    this.div.addEventListener("click", toggleDirection);

}
```

The behaviour I want is that when the div is clicked the Char Counter switches between counting down ('15 chars left') and counting up ('30 of 45 chars'). I store the state of the char counter in localStorage so that whatever state the user left the char counter in they will find it that way when they come back to it.

Now this code actually works fine but I can't escape the feeling that there is a more elegant way of doing it. I had to add the `var that = this` to get it to work but I always feel like that is a 'hack' and I try to avoid it if I can.

Can you think of a better way of achieving this or should I stop trying to fix what isn't broke?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `var that = this` trick is quite common in JavaScript.

The alternative is to bind the function to a given context:

```
function bind(context, fun) {
    return function() {
        fun.call(context, arguments);
    };
}
```

This function returns a function that, when called, will call `fun` with the given `context`.

You can use it like this:

```
this.div.addEventListener("click", bind(this, toggleDirection));
```

With this, `toggleDirection` will be called with `this` as context (`this` in `toggleDirection` will be the same as the one at the time you called `addEventListener`).

See also [`Function.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

Comment: Thank you. I looked into `call` and `apply` but I couldn't get my head around them. I thought I got it but I tried using them to achieve this and it didn't work. Your answer is making them a little clearer.

Comment: Since it's a Chrome Extension and therefore I don't have to worry about browser incompatibility does that mean I can use it like this `this.div.addEventListener("click", toggleDirection.bind(this));`?